# jQuery hide and show toggle keeping active only one div

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show, toggleclass

I am a starter with JQuery, and Javascript, and I would like to know how should I edit the following code so that when I click on a heading, the content under the other headings, will be hidden? I also want the arrows to function properly.

Basically, I want to keep only one content active when clicking on a heading?

Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/1/

```
$(".prod_options").hide();
$(".stag_options").hide();
$(".qa_options").hide();

$("#show_prod_options").click(function(){
    $(".prod_options").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#arrow_prod").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
$("#show_stag_options").click(function(){
    $(".stag_options").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#arrow_stag").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
$("#show_qa_options").click(function(){
    $(".qa_options").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#arrow_qa").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: With multiple options, you may get better results with .addClass and .removeClass rather than toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/13/

HTML (repeat for each option you require):

```
<div class="env_menu_options dropMenu" id="stag_env_menu_options">
    <div class="env_list" id="show_stag_options">
        <span id="arrow_stag" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down arrow"></span> Heading 2
    </div>
    <div class="stag_options detail">Content 2 <br>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.detail {
    display:none;   
}
```

JS:

```
$(".dropMenu").on("click", function () {
    var notThisOne = $(this);

    $(".dropMenu").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") !== notThisOne.attr("id")) {            
            $(this).find(".arrow").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
            $(this).find(".detail").slideUp("slow");
        } 
        else {
            $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
            $(this).find(".detail").slideToggle("slow");                
        }        
    });    
});
```

Comment: I have added "detail" and "arrow" to the classes, however it does not work, as the contents will not show at all. (Please view http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/7/). Also, the arrows do toggle, however, I would need to toggle also when clicking on the active heading (so that it can collapse, and all content to be hidden).

Comment: Basically, I would need the following: at first, all content to be hidden, and then while clicking on any of the headings, its content to be shown, and when clicking again on it, hide its content. Or, when clicking on an alternative heading, the previous content to be hidden, and current to be shown. Thanks!

Comment: @DantèsCristo - See my subtle edit... I'd made a casing error in _Options (should be _options). Simply change three letters and you're done.

Comment: @ Jeff Watkins - It works now! I forgot that classes are case sensitive. Thank you for this! Is there any way that I can make some conditioning which will work as when I click on any active heading, it will collapse it?  At the moment, I can collapse an active heading + content while clicking on a different heading. Is there something that I can implement so that it collapses when clicking on itself (+ also the arrow to work)? Here is the corrected code: http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/9/

Comment: @ Jeff Watkins - I forgot to add, for some reason the neater update works only here http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/10/ and not on my local document. Any idea why this would be? thanks

Comment: @DantèsCristo - See my update to fix toggling, also way neater. As for your other problem, you may have to message me your full source.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide you with the full source due to confidential data, however it might be a conflict between the libraries I used. I added as external sources all the libraries I use in my files here http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/15/. It seems that there is a conflict 1.4.4 jQuery library and the one you used, 1.9.1. I am not sure of the migration process between libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I was the one who used the 1.9.1 from the beginning in the JSFiddle by mistake.

Comment: I managed to correct the library issue, as the order seemed to cause the issue in my local files, however I noticed that when I click inside the content (for example Content1), it behaves as if I clicked on its heading. Is there a way to avoid this happening? Basically, when I click in the content (in the original file I have some checkboxes), I do not want the fields to hide. Here is an updated jsfiddle where I added some borders, to better understand the containers: http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/16/

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got a couple of sections, keep it simple with .slideUp() and .slideDown() - see updated jsfiddle:

```
  $(".prod_options").hide();
    $(".stag_options").hide();
    $(".qa_options").hide();

    $("#show_prod_options").click(function(){
        $(".prod_options").slideDown("slow");
    $(".stag_options").slideUp();
    $(".qa_options").slideUp();

        $("#arrow_prod").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
    $("#show_stag_options").click(function(){
        $(".stag_options").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".prod_options").slideUp();
    $(".qa_options").slideUp();
        $("#arrow_stag").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
    $("#show_qa_options").click(function(){
        $(".qa_options").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".prod_options").slideUp();
    $(".stag_options").slideUp();
        $("#arrow_qa").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/4/

Comment: For some reason, https://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/4/ does not show the arrows at all, however I copied the code here http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/6/ and they appear. However, the arrows do not toggle properly. The expected result would be when I click on heading 1, the other contents hide (which works), but the arrows will not toggle properly. All inactive headings should show down, and active heading show up, which is not working here. Also, when I click on an already active heading, it should collapse its content, but here, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an if conditional so that when I click on an active heading it just simply collapses all content. I have added the conditional to **Jeff Watkins'** code, and it works perfectly. Below it is the conditional, and here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/mL79571z/12/

```
$("#show_prod_options").click(function(){ 
if( $('#arrow_prod').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down') ){
   expand("#arrow_prod", ".prod_options");              
} else {
   collapse();
}
```

});

Thank you for all of your help!